# Need advice: How to share a potentially large report to remote users?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, report

I am asking for advice on possibly better solutions for the part of the project I'm working on. I'll first give some background and then my current thoughts.

### Background

- Our clients can use my company's products to generate potentially **large data sets** for use in their industry. When the data sets are generated, the clients will file a processing request to us.
- We want to send the clients **a summary email** which contains some statistical charts as well as sampling points from the data sets so they can do some initial quality control work. If the data sets are of bad quality, they don't need to file any request.
- **One problem** is that the charts and sampling points can be **potentially too large to be sent in an email**. The charts and the sampling points we want to include in the emails are pictures. Although we can use low-quality format such as JPEG to save space, we cannot control how many data sets would be included in the summary email, so the total size could still exceed the normal email size limit.
- In terms of **technologies**, we are mainly developing in Python on Ubuntu 14.04.

### Goals of the Solution

- In general, we want to present a report-like thing to the clients to do some initial QA. The report may contains external links but does not need to be very interactive. In other words, a static report should be fine.
- We want to **reduce the steps or things that our clients must do to read the report**. For example, if the report can be just an email, the user only needs to 1). log in and 2). open the email. If they use a client software, they may skip 1). and just open and begin to read.
- We also want to **minimize the burden of maintaining extra user accounts** for both us and our clients. For example, if the solution requires us to register a new user account, this solution is, although **still acceptable**, not ranked very high.
- **Security is important** because our clients don't want their reports to be read by unauthorized third parties.
- We want the process **automated**. We want the solution to provide programming interface so that we can automate the report sending/sharing process.
- **Performance is NOT a critical issue**. Our user base is not large. I think at most in hundreds. They also don't generate data that frequently, at most once a week. We don't need real-time response. Even a delay of a few hours is still acceptable.

### My Current Thoughts of Solution

- Possible solution #1: **In-house web service**. I can set up a server machine and develop our own web service. We put the report into our database and the clients can then query via the Internet.
- Possible solution #2: **Amazon Web Service**. AWS is quite mature but I'm not sure if they could be expensive because so far we just wanna share a report with our remote clients which doesn't look like a big deal to use AWS.
- Possible solution #3: **Google Drive**. I know Google Drive provides API to do uploading and sharing programmatically, but I think we need to register a dedicated Google account to use that.

Any better solutions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly use AWS S3 and Cloudfront.  Files can easily be loaded into S3 using the AWS SDK's and API.  You can then use the API to generate secure links to the files that can only be opened for a specific time and optionally from a specific IP.
Files on S3 can also be automatically cleaned up after a specific time if needed using lifecycle rules.
Storage and transfer prices are fairly cheap with AWS and remember that the S3 storage cost indicated is by the month so if you only have an object loaded for a few days then you only pay for a few days.
S3: http://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing

Cloudfront: https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/

Here's a list of the SDK's for AWS:
https://aws.amazon.com/tools/#sdk

Or you can use their command line tools for Windows batch or powershell scripting:
https://aws.amazon.com/tools/#cli

Here's some info on how the private content urls are created:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html

Comment: Thanks for the info and details! I think S3 + Cloudfront might be a good solution and I'm looking into the documents.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to built this service using mix of your #1 and #2 options. You can do the processing and for transferring the data leverage AWS S3 which is quiet cheap.

Example: 100GB costs like approx $3.

Also AWS S3 will be beneficial as you are covered for any disaster on your local environment your data will be safe in S3.

For security you can leverage data encryption and signed URLS in AWS S3.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'm looking at the documents provided by JeffR and see which solution might work better for me! I think I get ideas from both of you but it looks like I cannot accept both answers..